# How can I, search a code by auto generated classes names in css-in-js Emotion?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, emotion

In the project, I ran into CSS-IN-JS implemented using Emotion. Usually, I look for the code of corresponding components by the names of the CSS styles, but due to the generated styles names, I feel a lot of pain when I tried to find an element from the browser in project code.

Actually, the question is, can I somehow add "names" for Emotion styles, so that at least part of the generated name will be human-readable?

If it is impossible, share how you find the “element” that you see in the browser in the project code?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emotion provides a way of appending a label to the end of the class name, via a `label` prop. You can read about it in the [official docs](https://emotion.sh/docs/labels).